# abstract algebra equivalence relations

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R be the set of real numbers. For a,b∈R define a∼b if a − b ∈ Z. Prove that ∼ is an equivalence relation.

I know you have to prove that it's reflexive, symmetric, and transitive I just don't know how to show my work.

Comment: Go look around the site.  There are hundreds if not thousands of examples of questions just like this.  You may know this equivalence relation by a different name, "*having the same fractional part.*"  For example, $1.73\sim 3.73$ as well as $2\sim 5$ etc...  Show that for any $x\in \Bbb R$ one has $x\sim x$.  Show that *if* $x\sim y$ that $y\sim x$.  Finally show that if $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$ that $x\sim z$.  As a hint, use your definitions and remember that zero is an integer, the negative of an integer is an integer, and an integer plus an integer is again an integer.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  [For some basic information about writing math](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)
at this site see e.g. [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation),
[mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020),
[main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559)
and [equation editikng how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\sim y$ thus $x-y\in\mathbb Z$, which gives $y-x\in\mathbb Z$, which says $y\sim x$.

$x-x\in\mathbb Z$, which says $x\sim x$.

Let $x\sim y$ and $y\sim z$.

Thus, $x-y\in\mathbb Z$ and $y-z\in\mathbb Z$, which gives
$$x-z=x-y+y-z\in\mathbb Z,$$ which says $x\sim z$ and we are done!

Comment: $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! It was typo. I fixed.